# Mysql SUM output is wrong

Tags: mysql, count, sum, left-join

I have a query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
g.thumb, h.hotel_name, h.id, COUNT(c.id) as total_comments, SUM(c.rating) AS total_ratings
FROM 
at_hotels h 
LEFT JOIN 
at_gallery g 
ON 
h.id = g.h_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
at_comments c
ON
h.id = c.h_id AND c.status = '1'
GROUP BY h.id 
ORDER BY h.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Query is working except SUM(rating). Sum command is giving more than expected. I also tried SUM command like this :

```
--query
(SELECT SUM(rating) FROM at_comments WHERE at_comments.h_id = at_hotels.id) AS total
--more query
```

and this is not worked too.

total must be : 13, but this is giving 36. Where is the problem?

Sample Data : (Comments Table)

```
id h_id rating
----------
1 | 1  |5
----------
2 | 1  |3
----------
3 | 1  |5
```

My Tables :

[image: Tables]

Comment: Run the query without the `GROUP BY` to see if you are getting some unexpected record duplication due to your joins.

Comment: One more thing, i removed distinct and tried but nothing changed. Still same problem.

Comment: @a'r Also tried, but nothing happend.

Comment: Can you post sample data along with current results and expected results? Knowing that its returning 36 instead of 13 doesn't help since we don't have context.

Comment: Firstly try to run this query without joining `at_gallery` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

The problem was the 'rating' row DATA TYPE.

Rating row datatype was 'SET' and the values 1,2,3,4,5.

I changed data type to the TINYINT, records are automatically changed like this :

```
5 -> 16
3 -> 4
5 -> 16

16 + 4 + 16 = 36
```

So, summing 'SET' data type is buggy or something?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely dependent on your data (that we cannot see), but I'd suggest not relying on MySQL to do "the right thing" for your grouping, but to explicitly `GROUP BY` them:

```
SELECT 
MAX(g.thumb), h.hotel_name, h.id, COUNT(c.id) as total_comments, SUM(c.rating) AS total_ratings
FROM 
at_hotels h 
LEFT JOIN 
at_gallery g 
ON 
h.id = g.h_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
at_comments c
ON
h.id = c.h_id AND c.status = '1'
GROUP BY h.id, h.hotel_name
ORDER BY h.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I'v uplaod an image so you can see the data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, lose the `DISTINCT` - it isn't needed.
Secondly, format your query so it is readable, like this kind of formatting:

```
SELECT
  g.thumb,
  h.hotel_name,
  h.id,
  COUNT(c.id) as total_comments,
  SUM(c.rating) AS total_ratings
FROM at_hotels h 
LEFT JOIN at_gallery g ON h.id = g.h_id -- put join, tablee and on clause on same line
LEFT JOIN at_comments c ON h.id = c.h_id AND c.status = '1' -- removed OUTER: redundant
GROUP BY 1,2,3 
ORDER BY h.id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Thirdly (already done above), add in non-aggregate columns to `GROUP BY` - I prefer using numbers - it's clearer.

See how that goes.